# "substring not found" what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, encryption

i want to encrypt this password and I tried to put it in a loop to do all the letter's and it keeps coming up with the error "substring not found" pls help I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
   n_pword = "hello"
    split_n_pword = []
    n=0
    
    for letter in n_pword:
        split_n_pword.append(letter)
    
    print(split_n_pword)
    
    encrypt = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for letter in n_pword:
        index = array.index(split_n_pword[n])
        ceaser = 2
        encrypted_letter = encrypt[index-ceaser]
        n=n+1
    print(encrypted_letter)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the logic used.The `array` list seems to be undefined .Please do provide information on what the array list contains.

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing Casear cipher your code seems to have several issues. First this is a version of code that encrypt and decrypt data.

```
# Make program more robust so it can encrypt uppercase letters also
n_pword = input("Enter text to encrypt it using caser cipher: ").lower()

# It's also better to include numbers so you can include numbers in your plaintext
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
ciphertext = ""
casear_shift_value = 1

for letter in n_pword:
    index = alphabet.index(letter)

# we use mod 36 (26 alphabet + 10 digits 'from 0 to 9')
    ciphertext += alphabet[(index + casear_shift_value) % 36]
print("Encrypted Text {}".format(ciphertext))

# decrypt back
plaintext_back = ""
for letter in ciphertext:
    index = alphabet.index(letter)
    # Reverse operation
    plaintext_back += alphabet[(index - casear_shift_value) % 36]
print("Decrypted plaintext {}".format(plaintext_back))
```

The issues: first in Caesar cipher the shift value doesn't change.Second you are trying to use non declared variable `array` which will raise an error. Also, there is no need to convert the user imputed string into an array, python strings can be iterated over but you can consider converting this input to lowercase so program can work in nearly all cases(will fail if user inputted some special characters).

Comment: @ArtjomB. yeah you are right thanks added it as a code comment. You are also free to edit the answer to give better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this what your trying to do
find the index of letter in a word
reduce 2 from it
get the letter in that location from encrypt, and add it to encrypted_letter

```
n_pword = "hello"
split_n_pword = []
for letter in n_pword: # you can use split_n_pword = list(n_pword)
    split_n_pword.append(letter)
n = 0
encrypt = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
encrypted_letter = "" # you need to create the string before appending to it
for letter in n_pword:
    my_index = n_pword.index(split_n_pword[n]) #index is a string method 
    ceaser = 2
    encrypted_letter += encrypt[my_index-ceaser]
    n+=1
```

you can get the same result with

```
n_pword = "hello"
encrypt = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
encrypted_letter = ""
ceaser = 2
for letter in n_pword:
    my_index = n_pword.index(letter )
    encrypted_letter += encrypt[my_index-ceaser]
```

Comment: OP tries to implement the Caesar cipher. Your reduced code has two issues.